# Allow users to put their e-mail in posts?

Tags: discussion, questions, email, inappropriate-content

Should I edit out the (thankfully obsfucated) e-mail address from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185598/java-to-c-cross-compilation)?  Is this something we should allow on the site going forward?

I don't care about the "thank you" or "hello", but this might lead to an answer being sent by e-mail, which would mean it wouldn't be peer reviewed (for what that's worth), and the answer would be lost to the community.

Answer (score 11):

I went ahead and removed it.

We don't email answers to people.  It totally removes the aspect of people finding answers to their problems on Stack Overflow through google.

Comment: Well, if an SO user would be willing to give one-on-one consulting sessions on a difficult topic to somebody, then I'd say go ahead. After all, it's none of Stack Overflow's business how its users communicate with each other. I agree with removing the E-Mail address as noise, though - it's extremely bad form to ask for answers through E-Mail.

Comment: @Pekka I disagree.  Stackoverflow should not facilitate one-on-one help.  That is not the intent of the site.  If someone wants to go out of their way to contact someone, that's their choice.  But having a policy that explicitly says that it is Ok is against the aim of the site.

Comment: Nelson, I think we agree more than we disagree. I am totally for answering all questions on SO - it's what makes most sense. I have done a lot of lenghty "can you change x to y?" "ok, can you check whether a is n?" support sessions in the comments to an answer myself. But if both asker and askee *want* to, as you say, go out of their way to contact each other directly, it's none of SO's business. I agree with what you say about policy.

Comment: If two SO users want to contact each other, there are a million ways for us to find each other already. However, it does **not** belong in posts. (For example, several SO users follow me on Twitter and vice versa. My Twitter URL and obfuscated email are both in my profiles; I'm not hard to find. But @jinguy's right -- it shouldn't necessarily be facilitated.)

Answer (score 8):

Answers are for the benefit of the Stack Overflow community not just for the OP. So tacking on your email address to a question (perhaps) in the hope of a direct and private answer is up there with the same sin committed by Usenet folks who request that you "plz reply directly to email".

Answer (score 6):

It's noise. Like "Howdy" and "Thanks to all my peeps, peace out!". Get rid of it! (In this case you do not have to do anything though; someone was faster)

Answer (score 6):

The only reasons to include an email in a post might be to

- Arrange a personal contact
- Converse about the post off the site

Both of which move the site in directions that have been declined time and time again for the following reasons:

- SO is not a social networking website.
- Questions and answers are meant to appear onsite so that future SO users may benefit.

The site already has a feature to email the question owner if they want to receive updates via email.

In 5 years the email will have absolutely no value or bearing on the question.

Therefore it doesn't belong - there's no reason to have it now, and there's no reason to have it long term.

Answer (score -3):

If someone want's to post their email, let them.  I don't think it's a great idea though.

Comment: If they want to give you their email address, the correct place to put it is on their user page.

Comment: @Brad, yes, I think obfuscated on the user page is the best option, but we shouldn't restrict people from putting it in their post if they want.

Comment: Why obfuscated? If they want to put it in plan text, let them

Comment: @Down, it's intelligent to obfuscate it so spambots don't get it